# Send data from html template to php without POST or GET

Tags: php, html, smarty3

I'm using `Smarty` with `PHP`. I'm trying to get `the combobox value` from the html part to the **PHP** to use it later to get data from database.

Every time the combobox value changes I have to send this value to my PHP code.

I can send data from PHP to my template HTML with smarty but I don't know how to do the inverse. 
How to send data from the HTML template to PHP?

Comment: How about cookie or session?

Comment: sending data from `HTML template` to `PHP` ....where does `get` and `post` come in here as mentioned in your *title*????

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by 'send to php'. Are you trying to store it in a variable for a later script run?

Comment: sending data without `GET` or `POST`.... sounds like *cooking food without fire or microwave!!* :)

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so far and why you want to avoid POST and GET?

Comment: @Sidstar I'm trying to get the combobox value in the html file and then use this value to get data from database so that all the input field values should be filled in . I'm avoiding post and get because I don't want to load the page again to fill in just the input field

Comment: If you just want to make a request to a script and then get the data back, use `ajax` (in case you use javascript), as the current answer stated. You will still have to use `POST` or `GET` but you will not have to reload the page.

Comment: @Jite yes this is what i mean

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX. But to do this you have to use GET or POST method.

Comment: **for anyone suggesting *this has to be a comment*, please be aware that answerer doesn't have rep for it!!** :)

Comment: Can you explain why this not answers question? This is correct answer and exactly what Ghada was looking for. Maybe a little bit short, but nevertheless correct.

Comment: Posting simple code explaining how to use Ajax will prevent from deleting this comment. Short answers without explanation or code are not answers. An answer should show some sort of effort.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 other methods

1. By appending the data with the URL using `<a>` tag like:
   www.abc.com?test=pppp&test2=tttttt
2. By using [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) in php;